# nginx return adds trailing slash to url

Tags: nginx, redirect

This redirect adds a trailing slash which breaks the link I would like to spend people to, the exact code follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name graphwhy.org;
    return 301 https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/nationaldebt$request_uri;
}
```

currently when someone enters `graphwhy.org` into their browser, they are redirected to `https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/nationaldebt/` this url is not acknowledged. Survey monkey will only recognize `https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/nationaldebt`

could someone help me remove the trailing slash. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the URL path to be appended to the redirected URL, by using `$request_uri`. Thus, if you go to `http://graphwhy.org/` you're redirected to `https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/nationaldebt/`, because the requested URI is `/`. Further, if you go to `http://graphwhy.org/because` then you are redirected to `https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/nationaldebt/because`, because it's `/because`.

If you just want people to be redirected to the same URL, regardless, then you should not have `$request_uri` here.